# Python difflib take new data and append to old file

Tags: python, diff

I am trying to monitor a log file, specifically /var/log/auth.log hourly and take the new entries and append them to a file I am building. My thought was to diff the entries from the hour before with what I have in my temporary file I am using and just append the diff.

```
import difflib
mostRecent = open('var/log/auth.log')
old = open('temp')

diff = difflib.ndiff(mostrecent.readlines(),old.readlines())
delta = ''.join(diff)
```

how do i append the diff to the old file?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add 'a' when you open 'temp' file, see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

```
old = open('temp', 'a') 
old.write(delta)
```